# tomcat url redirecting .local .com

Tags: java, tomcat, dns, url-routing, debian

I have Apache Tomcat 7 webserver ( on debian linux )in the local network, with port 80 open through the firewall ( WatchGuard  firebox XTM520 running 11.5.1 ) so the website can be publicly accessible.

but Now users have two different urls, " web . company . local " for local network and " web . company . com " otherwise. Is there anyway to automate this process so users can just use one url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a network issue (more than a Tomcat issue): you need to configure your LAN DNS.

The DNS you users are accessing on your local network must resolve web.company.com to the LAN/local IP address of the Tomcat sever, and your users should only use this server name.

Comment: Thank you! You are correct, it was a network issue. I contacted the network admin, he made couple of changes and it's fixed now

Comment: I really wish you would have explained those changes. Could you please post what changes were made? I have the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions:

- You can deploy an app which consists of a one .html file which redirects app to the new url on the old one.
- You can create a servlet filter, which will take a look at url which is visited by a user, and in case it's the old one, redirect it to the new one.

Comment: Konstantin, only one url works at a time. Thus, I am unable to redirect them in the same server or web project. For example, if user is connected to local network, his request for .com will not work. since it is NAT'd through the firewall. When the request is made for .com firewall allows it to go out but doesn't let it enter back in again.